# duda con Querys - BDOO

Tags: java, jpa

Tengo el siguiente código:

En la entidad `Article` tengo la siguiente `@NamedQuery`

```
@NamedQuery(name="Article.aumentapreu",

            query="UPDATE Article a SET a.preu=a.preu*:quantitat")
```

Y en clase gestor articulo:

```
/**
 * Incrementa el preu de tots els articles de la base de dades en un percentatge determinat    
 * @param percentantge tant per cent (%) d'increment 
 */
public void incrementarPreu(float percentantge){
    //TODO completar el metode
    Query ap = em.createNamedQuery("Article.aumentapreu");
    ap.setParameter("quantitat", percentantge);
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    ap.executeUpdate();
    em.getTransaction().commit();
}
```

El problema que tengo es que me da error porque me dice que la query solo admite parametros de entrada entre las clausulas WHERE o HAVING.

¿Alguna idea de como solucionarlo?

Comment: viendo el update le falta un where o vas actualizar todos los registros de la tabla Article ?

Comment: que version de JPA estas usando?

Comment: @RaulCacacho la idea es todos.

Comment: @MontseMkd ya resolviste tu problema??

Comment: @RaulCacacho a medias.. xD

Comment: @MontseMkd que te falta resolver o que no te esta funcionando jeje?

Comment: abri un nuevo debate por que son dos clases que se utilizan entre ellas y una si que me funciona que es la que tratamos aquí pero la otra no.. xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asumiendo que usas una versión superior o igual a JPA 2.1, segun la [documentacion](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/persistence-2_1-fr-eval-spec/index.html) tu `@NamedQuery` debería ser válida.

> Input parameters can only be used in the WHERE clause or HAVING clause
>   of a query or as the new value for an update item in the SET clause of
>   an update statement.

o en español:

> Los parámetros de entrada solo pueden ser usados en una cláusula *WHERE*
>   o *HAVING* de una consulta o como el nuevo valor de un item de
>   actualización en la cláusula *SET* de una sentencia de *update*

Sin embargo, puede ser que uses una implementación que no siga la especificación correctamente.

Por ejemplo eclipseLink tiene el siguiente [bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=454086) reportado.

---

Si usas JPA 2.0 en cambio, no puedes usar dichos parametros en la cláusula SET:

> Input  parameters  can  only  be  used  in the WHERE clause  or  HAVING clause  of  a query.

---

### ¿Que hacer si no puedes usar una versión mas reciente?

Algunas opciones:

1.- Puedes obtener todas las entidades que necesitas actualizar, establecerles sus nuevos valores y persistirlas a mano:

```
List<Article> articles = em.createQuery('SELECT a FROM Article a')
    .getResultList(); 
for (Article a : articles) {
    a.setPreu(a.getPreu() * percentantge);
    em.merge(a);
}
```

2.- Puedes construir la sentencia concatenando el parametro a mano:

```
String query = new StringBuilder("UPDATE Article a SET a.preu = a.preu * ")
    .append(percentantge)
    .build();
em.createQuery(query).executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Usamos eclipselink. Y no me funciona hay otra alternativa?

Comment: Bibliotecas junit 4.12, hamcrest 1.3, jdbc postgresql, eclipselink jpa 2.0. estoy obligada a usarlas.

Comment: Si usas JPA 2.0 entonces no puedes agregar parametros de entrada en la cláusula SET

Comment: y como puedo solucionarlo entonces?

Comment: la segunda forma que me pones no me funciona y la primera me da un error : junit.framework.AssertionFailedError
 at TestGestors.provaIncrementarPreuDistribuidor1(TestGestors.java:189)

Comment: es failed no error. es como si estuviera vacío es posible? :S

Comment: Y que te hace pensar que un test fallido implica que el codigo esta malo? Puede ser el test el que esta malo.

Comment: no digo que el código este malo.. simplemente que la primera manera no me funciona por que hay partes del código que me da como erroneas. Y el segundo me da un error.  El test no puedo modificarlo es una clase que me viene por defecto.. T_T